# not able to convert String "rejectedDate":"2018-03-29" to ZoneDate time format

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-parsing

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-03-29 16:15:30'
>   could not be parsed at index 10

```
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        OffsetDateTime date = 
 OffsetDateTime.parse(entry.getValue(), fmt);
                        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(entry.getKey()), date));
```

Comment: OffsetDateTime javadoc says:
A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00. 

Could it be that your date time formatter doesnt include time zone, and datetime?

Comment: This is a normal exception, because your text does not match your pattern. There is only enough data in temporal parsed with this format to construct a `LocalDate`. OffsetDateTime would need also `LocalTime` and `ZoneOffset`, which are missing. What's your use case here?

Answer (score 1):

You created a `DateTimeFormatter` with the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd" (year-month-day), but your input also contains "hours:minutes:seconds" (`2018-03-29 16:15:30`).

But even if you use the correct pattern, this will still throw an exception:

```
// now the pattern matches the input
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-29 16:15:30", fmt); // DateTimeParseException
```

That's because an `OffsetDateTime` also needs the UTC offset, and the input doesn't have it. You have some alternatives:

1. parse it to a `LocalDateTime`:

   ```
   DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-29 16:15:30", fmt);
   ```
2. if you really need `OffsetDateTime`, you'll have to arbitrarialy choose some offset for it. Example:

   ```
   LocalDateTime date = // parse the LocalDateTime as above

   // use offset +02:00
   OffsetDateTime odt = date.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
   ```

Or you can set a default value in the formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time pattern
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    // use some offset as default (0 is UTC)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
    .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-29 16:15:30", fmt);
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply Yes by putting Zone id it is able to parse. Thanks